# Not able to find run option in C++ - VS Code

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I recently started programming in C++ in VS Code. I am not able to find the run option to run my code, neither in the menu that shows on right-click, not the Code Runner Run button on the top left.

But if I make a python file (.py) surprisingly I am able to locate both of these in their respective places.

No code runner button:

[image: No code runner button]

No run code option:

[image: No run code option]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to try Ctrl + Shift + D, since this works for me for bringing up Run view.

Also, if that doesn't work, I would like to suggest refering onto this [page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the folder and not only the file.
**File > Open Folder > Select the folder of your c++ project**

You need also the compiler installed on your OS

Then you need to compile the file before run it. (C++ is a **compiled** programming language, it is not like Javascript)

Comment: Yes, I have already set up that much. I can run my code via terminal by commands, however, I am not able to find a simple run option in VS Code itself.